# Rows that have same value in a column, sum all values in another column and display 1 row

Tags: sql

Example Table user:

```
    ID | USER_ID | SCORE | 
    1  |  555    |   50  | 
    2  |  555    |   10  |
    3  |  555    |   20  |
    4  |  123    |   5   |
    5  |  123    |   5   |
    6  |  999    |   30  |
```

The result set should be like

```
ID | USER_ID | SCORE | COUNT |
1  |  555    |   80  |   3   |
2  |  123    |   10  |   2   |
3  |  999    |   30  |   1   |
```

Is it possible to generate a sql that can return the table above, so far I can only count the rows where certain user_id appear, but don't know how to sum and show for every user ?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, combined with SUM and COUNT.

Comment: @jarlh both, but solution for any can be usefull

Comment: Doesn't matter, only tag products directly involved. (Don't tell me you're using both Oracle and SQL Server, asking a newbie question like this.)

Comment: @jarlh ok, thanks for the hint

Comment: what is ID in your result table ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've included a column called "ID" in both the source data and desired results, but I'm going to assume that these ID values are not related and simply represent the row or line number - otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

In which case, you can simply use:

```
SELECT
   USER_ID,
   SUM(SCORE) AS SCORE,
   COUNT(USER_ID) AS COUNT
FROM 
  <Table>
GROUP BY
   USER_ID
```

If you really want to generate the ID column as well, then how you do this depends on the database platform being used. For example on Oracle you could use the ROWNUM pseudocolumn, on SQL Server you will need to use ROW_NUMBER() function (which also works for Oracle).

Answer (score -1):

```
     SELECT ID 
       ,sum(SCORE)
       ,count(USER_ID)
FROM   Table
GROUP BY
       ID
```

Comment: This will return correct result only if scores have same value per user_id

Comment: this is false answer :) grouping by ID won't sum the scores by user_id, you should group by user_id instead

Comment: @mounaim yes it should be group by user_id, but answer was edited

Comment: @kareem you need to give some explanation of why you think this answer will work - as it stands it doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think COUNT is the number of scores per user_id, if so, then your sql request should be :

```
SELECT
    ID,
    USER_ID,
    SUM(SCORE)AS SCORE,
    COUNT(SCORE)AS COUNT
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY
    USER_ID
```